# Hello I use perfexcrm api ,when i run this api in postman it is through 419 'Page Expired' error, How solve it?

Tags: api, rest, codeigniter, postman

I Enter token in header as well as I also add company in params after that it is throw 419 'Page Expired'
Api document:https://perfexcrm.themesic.com/apiguide/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can check**

1. First check are you using correct keys for activation
2. Then check is there is an expire time for the token

Comment: yes I can check

Answer (score 0):

Just renaming:

> modules/your_api/controllers/Api.php

to

> modules/your_api/controller/Your_api.php